# Export and Import Bookmarks in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, bookmarks

I have moved to a new computer at work and I would like to export my bookmarks from Lotus Notes on my old PC and import them to my new one. Is there an easy way to accomplish this or will I be stuck creating my bookmarks from scratch?

Comment: Please search the internet for an answer to your question. There should be plenty of "HowTo"s around on this topic. If you encounter a specific problem, you may want to issue a question in the respective forum. stackoverflow is about programming, i.e. if you need to convert all data yourself.

Answer (score 1):

copy bookmark.nsf from your old PC to your new one. You can find it in the data- directory of your notes- installation.

In a single user installation this is something like
C:\Program Files\Lotus\Notes\Data (<= Notes 7)
C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data (< Notes 9) or
C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data (Notes 9)

In a multi user installation it is in the User- profile in 
Local Settings\Application Data\Lotus\Notes\data

If you want to keep the "Desktop" (Tiles), then also copy desktopX.ndk, if you want to keep your personal addressbook, keep names.nsf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your bookmarks.nsf file from your old machine - it will be in the Notes folder within your installation of Lotus Notes

You can then import the nsf file into your new Lotus Notes installation